# Mosquitto mqtt on ubuntu for windows

Tags: bash, ubuntu, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to setup a mosquitto mqtt server on windows using bash on ubuntu on windows because the code I'm try to run is that of Linux but I've been getting this error. I've surfed through the internet for days now and still haven't found a solution,

```
1588558652: Warning: Mosquitto should not be run as root/administrator.
1588558652: mosquitto version 0.15 (build date 2018-09-05 15:14:14+0000) starting
1588558652: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1588558652: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1588558652: Error: Address already in use
```

Mind you I'm not a coder so I'm new to all of this. Thanks for helping...

Comment: You should be asking that in supseruser.com or unixstackexchange, or better askubuntu.com, maybe a windows forum..., there is no coding involve...

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you what is wrong:  Some other program already has port 1883 open and is using it....thus Mosquitto can't use it.

You can find out which program has port 1883 open by using something like this (Not sure if it works on all Ubuntu's, but works on my  v16.04.6 LTS):

```
netstat -pan | grep 1883
```

Comment: I tried this already and I got nothing but when entered just mosquitto to check the status. this is what I got                                                                                                  
1588567992: Warning: Mosquitto should not be run as root/administrator.
1588567992: mosquitto version 0.15 (build date 2018-09-05 15:14:14+0000) starting
1588567992: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1588567992: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1588567992: Error: Address already in use

Comment: Did you try and install Mosquitto on windows first?

Comment: @hardillb Yes I did but I had to switch to bash because the instructor I'm following is using Linux because like I said, I'm not a coder

Comment: Make sure the Windows Mosquitto service is stopped (probably best to remove it)

Comment: @hardillb I removed the windows mosquitto service, deleted the files and uninstalled from control panel. Still the same